# Table body not updating in react , when fetching data from firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, state, react-table

Im fetching some data from firebase and updating a state,but the tables not updating when the page loads. Althoght , the table updates if i make some changes to the file and save it.

Code -

```
  const [leaderdata, setdata] = useState({});
  const database = firebase.database().ref();

  useEffect(() => {
    var x = 0;
    //getting the data from firebase and storing it in a state
    database.orderByChild("ques_fund").once("child_added", (snapshot) => {
      var temp = leaderdata;
      temp[x] = snapshot.val();
      setdata(temp);
      x = x + 1;
    });
    console.log(leaderdata);
  }, []);


return (
    <div>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Rank</th>
            <th>Participant Name</th>
            <th>Score</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {leaderdata ? (
            Object.values(leaderdata).map((row, index) => {
              console.log("hi");
              return (
                <tr key={row.timestamp}>
                  <td>{index}</td>
                  <td>{row.name}</td>
                  <td>{row.ques_fund}</td>
                </tr>
              );
            })
          ) : (
            <h1>No data</h1>
          )}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
```

The console.log at the end of useEffect(which is leaderdata) gives  ->
[log at the end of use Effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VADok.png)

Comment: Can you please `console.log(leaderdata)` at the end of your useEffect and share the ouput?

Answer (score 0):

One rule of using react state is that you should not modify the state directly.

Modify your `useEffect` hook as:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  var x = 0;
  //getting the data from firebase and storing it in a state
  database.orderByChild("ques_fund").once("child_added", (snapshot) => {
    // var temp = leaderdata;
    // create another copy of state;
    var temp = {...leaderdata};
    temp[x] = snapshot.val();
    setdata(temp);
    x = x + 1;
  });
  console.log(leaderdata);
}, []);
```

After every `setState`, react compares whether the state has changed or not. For objects (array is an object), it is the reference which is compared. When you mutate an object, then the reference isn't modified.

You can verify it using this sample code

```js
const obj1 = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4};
const obj2 = obj1;  // use the original reference
const obj3 = {...obj1}; // created a new copy
obj1.a = 4;
obj3.a = 4;
console.log(obj1 === obj2); // true
console.log(obj1 === obj3); // false
```

You can read more such rules in official [React Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly)

Edit: changed the code to use objects.

Also, I realize that you should learn about spread operator too. Check more [Spread Syntax | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Comment: Hey , @Avinash i get what youre saying , but in my case leaderdata state is an object nt an array so by doing what you did (using the ...)i get and error , saying leaderdata are not iterable.

Comment: @Vedant Tewari, updated the answer. Also, you can learn more about spread operator from the link I added in answer.